# efficient way to make unique set from datamapper query

Tags: sql, ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I am am using DataMapper and Sinatra and I am trying to create a unique set of elements from a DataMapper entity property. I search the database for a collection of entries. These entries all have a "category" property. I would like to find an efficient way to make a new array of all unique category types.

thanks

Comment: and for that you did what? did you try using a ```Set```

Comment: yea I am using a set but I was wondering if the only way to do this is to iterate the entire list. Is there a Ruby function for reducing an array based on a filter?